# How to swipe nested Navigator over root Navigator?

Tags: flutter

https://dartpad.dev/?id=e2883acd6be0a1f1409ed60522fd10f0

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: Navigator(
        onGenerateInitialRoutes: (_, __) => [
          CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => Container()),
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  // width: 250.0,
                  height: 450.0,
                  child: Navigator(
                    onGenerateInitialRoutes: (_, __) => [
                      CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => Container()),
                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => Container(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On iOS swipe, the root navigator moves, while gesture event goes first from a blue (top) Container. If i uncomment `width: 250.0` for nested navigator, it swipes good. Why is that?
I see a popular scenario - few pages with a "common appbar and nested navigation in body" each. How to achieve that?

PS. don't mention about `WillPopScope` - the question is "how to activate a child navigator" rather than block all (there could be more) parent Navigators.